# Instantiating and setting size of a UIButton subclass with NSLayoutConstraint

Tags: uibutton, nslayoutconstraint

How do I set the size of a `UIButton` when instantiating it, ready to use for `NSLayoutConstraint`?

Code:

```
UIButtonRaisedSilver *loginButton = [UIButtonRaisedSilver buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[loginButton addTarget:self action:@selector(login) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[loginButton setTitle:@"Log in" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

NSDictionary *views = @{@"tableView" : self.tableView, @"loginButton": loginButton, @"signupButton": signupButton};

[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[tableView]-50-[loginButton()]"
                                        options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllCenterX
                                        metrics:nil
                                          views:views];
```

Answer (score 1):

It turns out, width and height are also part of the constraints system in iOS6/(OSX 10.8)(i think its 10.8 - havent developed for Mac OS yet).

Make sure the constraint is vertical for height and set the height in the brackets as below...

For example:

```
[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[loginButton(30)]"
                                    options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllCenterX
                                    metrics:nil
                                      views:views];
```